# Is the product of two functions which are measurable w.r.t different sigma-fields measureable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be random variables $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space). Let further $f,g:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be two functions such that $f$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and $g$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

Is then $fg$ measurable with respect to $\sigma(XY)$?

I tried beginning with the following:
$$
fg^{-1}((a,b)) = \{\omega \mid a<f(\omega)g(\omega)<b\}
$$
However, I got nowhere with this. Also, I searched on MSE but did not find anything that looked like an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})=((0,\infty),\mathcal{B}((0,\infty)))$ and

$$ X(\omega)=\omega, \quad Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega},$$

for all $\omega\in\Omega$. In particular, $XY\equiv 1$. Then, $f=X^2$ and $g=Y$ are measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ respectively, but $fg=X$ is not measurable with respect to $\sigma(XY)=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X=I_A$ and $Y=I_B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $f=I_A+1$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X)$ and  $g=I_B+1$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X)$ but $fg$ is not measurable w.r..t $\sigma (XY)$ becasue $XY=0$ and $\sigma (XY)$is the trivial sigma field.